# Dynamically creating controls in MFC (Collection question)

Tags: mfc, dynamic, controls, creation

I have some custom control inside of which i should create radiobuttons or checkboxes. The count of child controls is available only at runtime (it loads some file from which it  gets this count). So i need to create variable number of controls. Which collection i should use for this purpose?

Solution 1: simply use `std::vector<HWND>` (or `CArray<HWND>`) - not suitable because i want use MFC (CButton). Of course i can `Attach()` and later `Detach()` handle to window each time i need this window, but it will give big overhead.

Solution 2: use `std::vector<CButton*>` or `CArray<CButton*>` or `CList<CButton*>` or... In this case i take care about making 'new' and appropriate 'delete' when control is unneeded. I am forgetful :)

MFC handle map contains pointer to CButton and i can't use simple `CArray<CButton>`, because it will move my objects each time when his size will grow.

... and the question is:
Which collection i should use for containing variable count of MFC control classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to read your file with the Count parameter, create your buttons, work with them and later delete them all then `CArray<CButton*>` is fine in my opinion. To make sure the buttons get deleted you could wrap the CArray into a helper like:

```
class CMyButtonArrayWrapper
{
public:
    CMyButtonArrayWrapper();
    virtual ~CMyButtonArrayWrapper();

    void ClearArray();
    void Add(CButton* theButton);

private:
    CArray<CButton*> m_Array;
}

CMyButtonArrayWrapper::CMyButtonArrayWrapper()
{
}

CMyButtonArrayWrapper::~CMyButtonArrayWrapper()
{
    ClearArray();
}

void CMyButtonArrayWrapper::ClearArray()
{
    for (int i=0; i<m_Array.GetSize(); i++)
    {
        CButton* aButton=m_Array.GetAt(i);
        if (aButton)
            delete aButton;
    }
    m_Array.RemoveAll();
}

void CMyButtonArrayWrapper::Add(CButton* theButton)
{
    m_Array.Add(theButton);
}
```

Then add an object of this class as a member to your custom control (`m_MyButtonArrayWrapper`) and add your buttons with:

```
CButton* aButton=new CButton;
aButton->Create( ... );
m_MyButtonArrayWrapper.Add(aButton);
```

If you need to add and remove buttons randomly a `CList` might be better suited for performance reasons. (But you won't probably notice a performance difference using InsertAt/RemoveAt of CArray, except your UI has several thousands of buttons. I guess this would be more an artwork than a user interface :))

Comment: mmm... yes/ i need insertions only in tail of collection, then create window, then reuse it each time when 'another one' file is loaded. So simple CArray will be more suitable, because CList will give extra pointers to the 'left, right' elements...

thanks for the simple and clear answer